# Read value from several checkboxs in a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to javascript and have a question. I am using twitter bootstrap, rails and simpleform. I replaced checkboxes with toggles using javascript in my form. I am now trying to display the correct toggle option to the user using the same form when I edit.

When the form is displayed in the edit action, the toggle is selected for the checkbox value (1 or 0). The JS code below works for a single toggle element. I would like to know if it's possible to loop through all toggles if I gave them the same ID? I have more then 10 checkboxes in my form and don't want to duplicate JS.

```
var n = $('#hole_punch_buttons input[value=1]').length;
if(n === 1){
    $("#hole_punch_buttons a[data-value=1]").addClass('active')
}
else {
    $("#hole_punch_buttons a[data-value=0]").addClass('active')
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="hole_punch_buttons" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <div class="control-group hidden">
           <div class="controls">
               <input class="hidden" id="id_card_design_hole_punch" name="id_card_design[hole_punch]" type="hidden" value="1">
           </div>
       </div>
  <a class="btn ffbtn active" data-value="1">Yes</a>
  <a class="btn sfbtn" data-value="0">No</a>
</div>
```

Maybe there is a better way to write it altogether...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know if it's possible to loop through all toggles if I gave them the same ID?

No. IDs are unique. However, you can loop through them if you use a class.

Here's an example using `hole_punch_buttons` as a class:

```
<div class="btn-group hole_punch_buttons" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
```

And your rewritten JS:

```
$('div.hole_punch_buttons').each(function() {
    var n = $(this).find('input[value=1]').length;
    $(this).find('a[data-value=' + n + ']').addClass('active');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uKkq8/2/)

---

Another solution is to use `.val()` to retrieve the value of the hidden input and add the active class to the corresponding anchor's data-value:

```
$('div.hole_punch_buttons').each(function() {
    var n = $(this).find('input.hidden').val();
    $(this).find('a[data-value=' + n + ']').addClass('active');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uKkq8/3/)

Comment: This solution actually finds all data-value=1 and toggles "active". The result is every data-value=1 is active. Not exactly what I am looking for. I need to check the value of the hidden input of each toggle and addClass to the link with data-value 1 or 0 depending on what is stored in the database. I will play with your example and report back. Thanks!

Comment: @prodigerati Oh my bad, I didn't notice the hidden input. Updating answer in a sec.